# What does Nassim Taleb mean by 'half-point' correlation?

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

Last year, Nassim Taleb posted this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/nntaleb/status/1137582695666634752):

> For a correlation number between X and Y, what is the "half point" correlation between 0 and 1, that is, the correlation for which you have half the uncertainty about X if you observed Y ( or vice-versa) compared to not having observed Y?

The answer is apparently 0.87 (specifically, $\sqrt{3}/2)$, and it apparently comes from Equation (13) [here](https://twitter.com/nntaleb/status/1137586973131120640/photo/1):

[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: I have not look into the very details, it seems that he assume $(X, Y)$ are jointly normal with correlation $\rho$, and want to compare the marginal variance $Var[X]$ with conditional variance $Var[E[X|Y]]$. By law of total variance, $Var[X] = E[Var[X|Y]] + Var[E[X|Y]]$ so $Var[E[X|Y]] < Var[X]$. In particular now he concerns for which value of $\rho$ will  $Var[X] = 2Var[E[X|Y]]$. Note that this is a model-dependent result which only valid on jointly Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @BGM he is definitely assuming joint Gaussian, because he wanted to demonstrate the counter-intuitive result even for the class of random variables which economics and other social sciences normally concern themselves with.

Comment: Also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/484013/119261.